# About ROC curve in segmentation model

Tags: machine-learning, image-segmentation, roc

I know how to draw ROC curves about classification model for a one class. And I know how to plot ROC curves about classification model for many classes. But is there a way to plot ROC curves for a segmentation model? If so, tell me how

Comment: What do you want to get out of the ROC curve? [Statisticians have doubts about their utility.](https://mobile.twitter.com/f2harrell/status/1101595033382326273?lang=en) (Harrell wrote *Regression Modeling Strategies*.)

Comment: To expand on that, here is an analogy.  Suppose you want to quantify how much taller 18 year old boys are than 18 year old girls.  For an ROC curve you take for every value of h  the proportion of students taller than h who are boys.  Most analysts would find that looking at the distribution of height stratified by sex to yield a more direct assessment than that.

Answer (score 2):

When computing a ROC curve for classification, you treat each image (and its prediction) as a single "data point".
In image segmentation, you need to treat each *pixel* as a data point.

for example:

```py
from sklearn import metrics

y_true = []
y_pred = []
for img, true_seg in test_set:
  pred = model(img)  # get prediction for each pixel in the image
  y_true.append(true_seg.to_numpy().flatten())  # flatten all targets
  y_pred.append(pred.to_numpy().flatten())  # flatten all predictions

# concatenate all predictions and targets:
y_true = np.concatenate(y_true, axis=0)
y_pred = np.concatenate(y_pred, axis=0)
# copte the ROC curve
fpr, tpr, thresholds = metrics.roc_curve(y_true, y_pred)
```